# Error de INSERT INTO

Tags: php, javascript

Me podrían ayudar es que al momento de ejecutar mi código me bota `else` significando que esta mal.¿Qué debería hacer? Ya verifique MySQL y no encuentro ningún fallo. Ya probé la conexión, hasta el formulario pero aun así no encuentro el posible error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes en tu tabla `cedula` pero en tu código tienes `cc` con colocar el mismo nombre que en la tabla debería bastar

Comment: Gracia, tienes razón tenia que tener mas atención al llamar las columnas pero aun asi me sigue dando fallo .

Comment: además de lo anrterior, cuando preguntes no uses mayúsculas parece que gritaras, segundo el código no va como imagen sino como texto (salvo que sea absolutamente necesario)

Comment: Gracia. lo tomare mas en cuenta

Comment: include 'conexion.php';

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$movil = $_POST['telefono'];


$insert = " INSERT INTO cuenta( usuario, password, email, cedula, movil)
 VALUES('$usuario', '$password', '$email', $cedula, $movil)";


$peticion = mysqli_query( $insert, $dbdato );
if($peticion){
  echo 'lo lograste porfin';
}
else{
  echo 'vamos sigue intentando';
}

Comment: edita tu pregunta y coloca el código ahí, ahora para que se comprenda mejor lo que pasa cuando edites indica de manera clara el cambio que hiciste y el nuevo error que aparece, pero repito en la pregunta por favor

Comment: a listo gracias es que apenas estoy aprediendo a utilizar esta plataforma

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283759/error-en-insert-into

Comment: @JUANSEBASTIAN deberías editar *esta* pregunta con el código de la otra. No hacer una nueva. Te dejo acá mi comentario: Tenés al revés los parámetros de [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php). Primero va la conexión (`$dbdato`) y después el query (`$insert`).

Comment: Posible duplicado de [error en insert into](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283759/error-en-insert-into)

Comment: Por favor, no pongas fotos en lugar del código , ya que nos es mas difícil de leer

Answer (score -1):

El detalle es cuando estás preparando la query, tienes el campo **cc** y en tu BD el campo es nombrada **cedula**, quedaría de la siguiente manera ya optimizada:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cuenta(usuario, password, email, cedula, movil) VALUES ('$usuario','$password','$email','$cedula', movil)";


if(mysqli_query($query, $dbdato)){
    echo "Éxito";
}
else{
    echo "Falló";
}
```

Comment: Gracia, tienes razón  tenia que tener mas atención al llamar las columnas pero aun asi me sigue dando fallo .

Comment: bueno disculpe.