# error en insert into

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

me podrian colabora e tratado de que el codigo se ejecute pero no funciona que puedo hacer ya verifique el nombre de la columnas y como las llamo, tambien la conexion, de igual manera el formulario  lo que creo que falla es el INSERT INTO pero no en que o que estara fallando oara que el codigo no se ejecute adecuadamente.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';

$dbuser = 'root';

$dbpass = 'root';

$dbtabla ='dbcuentas';

$dbport = 3306;

 $conx = mysqli_connect("$dbhost:$dbport" , $dbuser , $dbpass);

   $dbdato = mysqli_select_db( $conx, $dbtabla );


$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];

$movil = $_POST['telefono'];



$insert = " INSERT INTO cuenta( usuario, password, email, cedula, movil)
 VALUES('$usuario', '$password', '$email', $cedula, $movil)";



$peticion = mysqli_query( $insert, $dbdato );

if($peticion){
  echo 'lo lograste porfin';
}

else{
  echo 'vamos sigue intentando';
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tenés al revés los parámetros de [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php). Primero va la conexión (`$dbdato`) y después el query (`$insert`).

Comment: Hola Juan! Para poder leer el error que estás obteniendo, puedes añadir el código `or die(mysqli_error($dbdato))` al final de la linea `$peticion = mysqli_query( $insert, $dbdato )`, antes del `;`, y deberías poder ver un mensaje de error en tu pantalla cuando falle la consulta

Comment: ya puse primero la conexion y despues el query, y le agrege el codigo que dando asi $peticion = mysqli_query( $dbdato, $insert) or die(mysqli_error($dbdato)); pero aun asi el codigo no se ejecuta y no me dice cual es el error disculpen. si molesto

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar vamos a cambiar la forma de hacer la conexión a la `BD`:

```
$conx = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbtabla);
```

Asi no hace falta que pongamos:

```
$dbdato = mysqli_select_db( $conx, $dbtabla );
```

También veo que tienes un campo `id` `AUTO_INCREMENT`, prueba a cambiar tu `query` así:

```
$insert = " INSERT INTO cuenta( id, usuario, password, email, cedula, movil)
 VALUES(DEFAULT, '$usuario', '$password', '$email', $cedula, $movil)";
```

Como te han dicho en los comentarios de arriba cambiar el orden de los parámetros a esta forma:

`$peticion = mysqli_query( $dbdato, $insert );`

Por ultimo comprobamos si hubo filas afectadas al lanzar la `query`:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conx)){
    echo 'lo lograste porfin';
}else{
    echo 'vamos sigue intentando';
}
```

Código completo:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$dbtabla ='dbcuentas';
$dbport = 3306;

$conx = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbtabla);

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$movil = $_POST['telefono'];

$insert = " INSERT INTO cuenta( id, usuario, password, email, cedula, movil)
 VALUES(DEFAULT, '$usuario', '$password', '$email', $cedula, $movil)";

$peticion = mysqli_query( $dbdato, $insert );

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conx)){
    echo 'lo lograste porfin';
}else{
    echo 'vamos sigue intentando';
}
```

Como información y mejora, tu código es vulnerable a inyecciones `SQL`, para evitar eso te dejo un enlace para que veas como se hacen sentencias preparadas para mejorar la seguridad de tu programa: [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Gracias, pero aun los datos no se insertan en la tabla de mysql , sera que de pronto es un problema de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Debes corregir la siguiente línea.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO cuenta( usuario, password, email, cedula, movil)
 VALUES('$usuario', '$password', '$email', $cedula, $movil)";
```

Eilimina las comitas simples '  ' de los values.

Quedaría así.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO cuenta( usuario, password, email, cedula, movil)
 VALUES($usuario, $password, $email, $cedula, $movil)";
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias pero aun asi no se insertan los datos en la tabla.